# Cannot find type 'UITableView' in scope

Tags: swift, swift-package

I am using swift package in several projects. In one of them, this package stopped compiling with error "Cannot find type 'any UITableView related type ' in scope". I can't fix it by any action.
I tried:

Clean Build folder
Reset Package Caches
Readd package
Clean DerivedData and restart xcode and computer
In different combinations

Of course, I didn't forget 'import UIKit'.

What action can I try else?

**UPDATE:**

Actually any type from UIKit is not visible in package.

All other packages do not have any problems with UIKit.

This package does not have any problems in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue. my answer may or may not help, but this is how I solved it.

what I saw: `Cannot find 'UITableView' in scope` & `Reference to member 'systemGray6' cannot be resolved without a contextual type`

what was my build: Mac

how I solved: change it to any iphone build. I changed my simulator to the iphone 15

i guess they are simply just not availble yet on mac

Answer (score -1):

Remove all `#import` in bridging header of files contained in pods libraries

Comment: Swift package do not contain pods or bridging headers. Sorry.